# The kit iphoneos-clang Qt 5.8.0 for iOS has configuration issues

Tags: c++, ios, qt, qt-creator

When I try build any project I have issue

```
** BUILD FAILED **


    The following build commands failed:
        Check dependencies
    (1 failure)
    make: *** [xcodebuild-release-device] Error 65
    The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
    Error while building/deploying project my_project (kit: iphoneos-clang Qt 5.8.0 for iOS)
    The kit iphoneos-clang Qt 5.8.0 for iOS has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
    When executing step "Make"
```

**How can I correctly configure iphoneos-clang?**

*PS I haven't any problem with iphonesimulator and Desktop Qt clang*

Comment: If you look at the configuration of this kit (Project > Manage kits...), do you see some warning/error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Qt Creator select menu `Build / Run qmake`.
2. Open XCode and build the configuration (created by qmake).

Once you'll adjust in XCode all iOS related stuff (AppleID, Provisioning Profile, etc.) the next time you'll be able to build your app in Qt Creator.